# Firefox addon development: how to create empty numeric or date boxes

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, add-in, xul

I'm trying to create a form with a few fields in XUL. I failed to find a way to create a numeric box and a datepicker with empty values. Textbox of type number has a default "0" value, I can change the default to different number, but I want the box to remain empty. The same goes for the datepicker element, I must specify a valid date, but I want it to be empty until the user decides to enter the date.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that everything has to have a default value as a result of [usability guidelines](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/defaults.html), though I can't find any concrete evidence of that in terms of official documentation (the addition of the empty and [emptyText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Property/emptyText) attributes in Firefox 3.0 are what led me to this hypothesis).  With this in mind, your only options would seem to be either to use a plan textbox, or to pick some defaults.  You could always ignore the numeric and date fields if they've not been changed, or perhaps provide an option to enable/disable the fields?

Comment: Thanks for the response, that was what I was worried the answer would be, lots more javascript to code. :-)